# Style mat-select value

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I hope someone can help me, I'm using angular material, I have this select, when I see the options it appears fine but if I select one the strong tag no longer appears, you know how I can style only that part, thanks in advance

```
<mat-select formControlName="projectId" placeholder="project" [disabled]="enableList">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let projects of arrayProjects" [value]="projects.nameProject" (click)="projectSelected(projects)">
                  {{projects.nameProject}} &nbsp; - <strong> {{projects.id}} </strong> - &nbsp; {{projects.PEP | pepFormat}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
```

[img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB480.png)
[img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtdFU.png)

Comment: Can you upload the pic so i can understand your problem

Comment: I already added them, the first is good the strong and the second is at the time I selected the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do, is customize the template that appears inside the select box when some option is selected. For that you can use the `mat-select-trigger` directive.

```
<mat-select #projectSelect formControlName="projectId" placeholder="project" [disabled]="enableList">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    {{projectSelect.value.nameProject}} &nbsp; - <strong> {{projectSelect.value.id}} </strong> - &nbsp; {{projectSelect.value.PEP | pepFormat}}
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let projects of arrayProjects" [value]="projects.nameProject" (click)="projectSelected(projects)">
    {{projects.nameProject}} &nbsp; - <strong> {{projects.id}} </strong> - &nbsp; {{projects.PEP | pepFormat}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Note that I used a template reference to access the select component value. Alternatively, you can use the `formControl` to get the value instead of the template reference. If you would prefer that, add the relevant TS code to your answer.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvosn8?file=src/app/select-custom-trigger-example.html)